# Printing out 2D Array, replacing the values

Tags: c++, if-statement, replace, multidimensional-array

it's my first time using arrays and I'm stuck on this.
How can I change the values inside a 2D array and print it out?

For example, I want to replace the 1s with "" (space) and the 2s with "`*`" and then print them out. How can i do that?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int Xshape[5][5] = {{2,1,1,1,2},
                        {1,2,1,2,1},
                        {1,1,2,1,1},
                        {1,2,1,2,1},
                        {2,1,1,1,2},

    };
    {
        for (int row = 0; row<5 ; row++)
        for (int column=0; column < 5; column++)
        {
            cout << Xshape[row][column] << endl;
        }

    }
    system("pause");

}
```

i think it has something to do with the if-else statement but i cant pull it off
can someone help me please?

Comment: Ehm.....what if-else statement?

Comment: Do you mind showing us the if-else statement you tried?

Comment: You not only don't have an `if..else` statement, but you're not trying to replace anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with a simple if-statement:

```
for (int column=0; column < 5; column++)
{
    int val = Xshape[row][column];
    if (val == 1){
        cout << " " << endl;
    }else if (val == 2){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }else{
        //  Handle error case of neither 0 nor 1.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean but you can change it in the following manner :
Xshape[row][col] = value;

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
for (int column=0; column < 5; column++)
{
  switch (Xshape[row][column])
  {
    case 1: cout << " " << endl;
            break;
    case 2: cout << "*" << endl;
            break;

    default:assert(0); 
            break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row<5 ; row++)
  { 
  for (int column=0; column < 5; column++)
   {
    if(Xshape[row][column]==1) cout << " ";
    else if(Xshape[row][column]==2) cout << "*";
   }
     cout << "\n";
  }
```